# Remove words from a dataframe column in a series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe, with some words in column 0:

```
stopwords

    0
1   a
2   ab
...
10  der
```

How can I remove this from a Series, which I got with `str.lower().str.split(expand=True).stack.value_counters()`:

```
Wordcount
die    293107
der    281475
...
```

So that all the word are removed (exact matching) which are in stopwords:

```
Wordcount
die 2931707
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the column of stopwords into a index column and then use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
stopwords = stopwords.set_index(0)
#no match
s3 = Wordcount[~Wordcount.index.isin(stopwords.index)]

#match
s4 = Wordcount[Wordcount.index.isin(stopwords.index)]
```

---

Or pass column to `isin` function:

```
#no match
s3 = Wordcount[~Wordcount.index.isin(stopwords[0])]

#match
s4 = Wordcount[Wordcount.index.isin(stopwords[0])]
```